# Node.js - Object.getPrototypeOf

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to set the prototype of an object.

However, sometimes I want to set/get the prototype of a string. Surprisingly, however, I get an error when I call:

```
var foo = 'baz';
Object.getPrototypeOf(foo);
```

It throws:

```
TypeError: Object.getPrototypeOf called on non-object
    at Function.getPrototypeOf (native)
```

Why is that, and how can I get around it?

I want to be to able to set and get the prototype of a string. The one weird thing is that I can do this without an error:

```
var myProto = {};

var foo = 'baz';
Object.setPrototypeOf(foo,myProto);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Primitive values don't have accessible prototypes.

```
var foo = "hello",
    bar = false;

foo.prototype; // undefined
bar.prototype; // undefined
```

For primitive values you have

- Null
- Boolean
- String
- Number
- Undefined
- Symbol (hello es6)

More information can be found on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive

Answer (score 4):

In JavaScript there are 7 datatypes: 6 *primitive* types and objects. The primitive types are Boolean, Null, Undefined, Number, String and Symbol.

```
var foo = 'baz';
```

Creates a primitive type String `'baz'`.

```
var foo = new String('baz');
Object.getPrototypeOf(foo); // String
```

Creates an object of type `String`.

Answer (score 1):

your `var foo` is a primitive object, so you wont be able to access its prototype, if you check the following link:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf

You get an example of exactly what you are doing, and says it will throw an `TypeError` like you got

As per the docs, you can do as follows:

> ```
> var proto = {};
> var obj = Object.create(proto);
> Object.getPrototypeOf(obj) === proto; // true
> ```

But I dont see any reference where you can call `Object.getPrototypeOf` from a string.

So you should create a new String object:

```
var foo = new String('baz');
```